# How to prove the connected sum of two closed aspherical n-manfolds (n >2) is not asperical?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, at.algebraic-topology

The intuitive idea is that the sphere connected the two manifolds is not contractible, which implies the (n-1)th homotopy group is not zero. Another argument, which I am not totally understand, uses the fact that the universal covering of an aspherical manifold has only one end. I am wondering if someone here could clarify these for me or give me a new argument.

Comment: More generally, if $M$ and $N$ are closed manifolds of dimension $n > 2$, then $M\# N$ is not aspherical unless one of them is $S^n$ and the other is aspherical.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If $N$ is an open contractible manifold of dimension at least two, then it has one end.  For instance, you can compute the zeroth reduced homology of $N$ minus a closed ball $B$ by using the long exact sequence for $(N,B)$ by using excision and the fact that $N$ is contractible.

If $M$ is a closed aspherical manifold of dimension at least three and $M$ is a connected sum of $M_1$ and $M_2$, then the fundamental group of $M$ is the free product of the the fundamental groups of $M_1$ and $M_2$.

If $M_1$ and $M_2$ are closed aspherical manifolds of dimension at least three, then their fundamental groups are nontrivial, and so $\pi_{1}(M)$ would be a nontrivial free product.  But the universal universal cover of $M$ is one ended, and one ended groups do not decompose as nontrivial free products.

Answer (score 15):

Here's a different way to see it. Let $M$ and $N$ be aspherical of dimension at least 3.
Then the wedge $M \vee N$ is aspherical (but not a manifold). Let $M\sharp N$ be the connected sum. Then we get a collapse map $M\sharp N \to M \vee N$ given by pinching to a point the embedded $(n-1)$-sphere you used to form the connected sum. It is trivial to check that this map is $(n-1)$-connected, and therefore an isomorphism of fundamental
groups.

If the connected sum were  <s>acyclic</s>  aspherical then it would have to be homotopy equivalent to
the wedge, since the latter is  <s>acyclic</s>  aspherical and has the same fundamental group. Moreover,
the collapse map would have to give such a homotopy equivalence. But this is ludicrous,
since that would violate the long exact homology sequence of the cofibration
$$
S^{n-1} \to M\sharp N \to M \vee N .
$$

Comment: By the way, this argument generalizes to connected sums of acyclic Poincare duality spaces.

Answer (score 11):

In fact if $M$ is a closed aspherical $n$-manifold, then $\pi_1(M)$
does not split as an amalgamated product or HNN extension over a subgroup $H$ of cohomological dimension $\le n-2$. For concreteness suppose $\pi_1(M)=A*_C B$. Look at Mayer-Vietoris sequences of the splitting in dimension $n$ with $\mathbb Z_2$-coefficients. The factors $A$, $B$ have infinite index in $\pi_1(M)$, so their $n$-dimensional cohomology vanish, and so does the $(n-1)$-cohomology of $C$. By exactness, $H^n(M;\mathbb Z_2)$ vanishes, so $M$ cannot be closed aspherical.

Answer (score 4):

Darryl McCullough gives a very complete answer to your question in his ["Connected Sums of Aspherical Manifolds"](http://www.iumj.indiana.edu/docs/30002/30002.asp) paper. Let  $M$ be the connected sum of $g$ aspherical manifolds of dimension $d\geq 3$. Its universal cover $\tilde M$ is homotopy equivalent to $\bigvee_{\rho \in \pi_1(M)} \bigvee_{i=1}^{g-1}S^{d-1}$ (and in particular is not contractible).

I wonder if there is a short proof of this along the lines of Robert Bell's answer.