# Metric of negative curvature on connected sum

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $(M_1,g_1)$ and $(M_2,g_2)$ be two Riemannian manifolds of dimension $n\geq 2$. If we consider the connected sum $M=M_1\mathbin{\#}M_2$ of the two manifolds; can one get a smooth metric $g$ on $M$ with constant negative curvature. Is there any such construction available in the literature or can be done? As I am not aware about it, any insight will be very beneficial.

Comment: No in dimension $n>2$ because the connected sum of two manifolds other than $M, N$ has non-contractible universal cover (https://mathoverflow.net/a/51892/40804), unlike a manifold of nonpositive curvature. Yes for $n=2$ by uniformization, though it's not clear how you want the new metric to be related to the old ones.

Comment: You probably mean complete metrics. Then Mike's comment settles the matter.

Comment: If $M$ and $N$ are both the 2-sphere, no.